# Circloid with non-empty interior

Tags: general-topology

By a "circloid" I mean a continuum in the plane which separates the plane into exactly two components and minimal with respect to these properties, i.e. has no proper subcontinuum which separates the plane into exactly two components.

Can any one give an example of a circloid with non-empty interior?

Answer (score 1):

No, such a thing cannot exist. If your circloid has nonempty interior, then it will contain an open disk, and then it will in particular contain a circle that fits into this open disk as a proper subset, so it will fail the minimality part of the definition.